# Video image analysis - Detect fast movement / Ignore slow movement

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, motion-detection

I am looking to capture video on an iPhone and to initiate capture once fast motion is identified and to stop when there is slow motion or no motion is detected.

Here is a use case to illustrate:

1. If someone is holding the iPhone camera and there is no background movement, but his hands are not steady and moving left/right/up/down slowly, this movement should be considered slow.
2. If someone runs into the camera field of view quickly, this would be considered fast movement for recording.
3. If someone slowly walks into the camera field of view, this would be considered slow and shouldn't be picked up.

I was considering OpenCV and thought it maybe overkill using their motion detection and optical flow algorithms.  I am thinking of a lightweight method by accessing the image pixel directly, perhaps examining changes in luminosity/brightness levels.

I only need to process 30-40% of the video frame area for motion (e.g. top half of screen), and can perhaps pick up every other pixel to process.  The reason for a lightweight algorithm is because it will need to be very fast < 4ms as it will be processing incoming video buffer frames at a high frame rate.

Appreciate any thoughts into alternative image processing / fast motion detection routines by examining image pixels directly.

Comment: I see three ways: 1. dense optical flow 2. a very good object segmentation and semantic understanding combined with some feature matching. BOTH will be too slow and 2. will be impossible to develop. Good Luck. the Third way would be some general motion stabilization combined with sparse feature matching. Not sure whether this can be fast enough and robust enough.

Comment: In general you might get problems distinguishing far-away-fast-motion from near-slow-motion.

Answer (score 0):

1. dense optical flow like calcOpticalFlowFarneback
2. using motion history

   2.1  updateMotionHistory(silh, mhi, timestamp, MHI_DURATION);

   2.2  calcMotionGradient(mhi, mask, orient, MAX_TIME_DELTA, MIN_TIME_DELTA...

   2.3  segmentMotion(mhi, segmask, regions, timestamp, MAX_TIME_DELTA);

   2.4  calcGlobalOrientation(orient_roi, mask_roi, mhi_roi, ...